# SVN not detecting changes when overwriting file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been working with SVN successfully for a few weeks however I recently received an updated version of the code I'm working on from our vendor. I overwrote my local installation with the updated files and was expecting to be able to commit the updates files and everyone else would then get the updated version. However, when I overwrite my local files, SVN does not detect that the files have been updated. I'm using Tortoise SVN if that matters.

Update: I'm not copying over a working copy of the updated code (there are no .svn folders in the source.) However, I have noticed that the last modified dates on the files are older than the ones they replaced - Would that prevent SVN from detecting a change? Also the majority of the files are encrypted using ioncube.

Comment: Are you sure that those newer files really differ from the ones you had?

Comment: Yes, its an incremental update, so all files contain updated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local svn data is inside every directory of you working copy (in the .svn directory under every directory). So if you have copied a directory from the new code over a directory of your code, including subdirectories, you may have copied their .svn directories as well. That means svn can't know that it is changed.

If you want to do a recursive replace of code in a directory, you should make sure that the code you paste onto your existing code isnt itself a working copy, or that it has been stripped from .svn directories. To get a non-wc copy of a repository you can use svn export.

The latest version of subversion solves this problem by storing metadata only in the wc root, rather than in all subdirectories.

Comment: The files I copied over were part of a working copy (no .svn directories).

Comment: You mean you only copied over some files (no directories at all), or you copied directories but with the .svn subdirectories removed?

Comment: The tarball I received from the vendor consists of 5 directories and a dozen or so files and no .svn directories. I have put the code under revision control, the vendor is not using any revision control. I copied the files into the root of my app overwriting the existing files with the same name.

Comment: For one of the files that you know was updated byt the vendor code (say. file1.c), try right-clicking and select "show differences". No differences? Open the file .\svn\text-base\file1.c.svn-base (which is your original file). Does it exist? Does it differ from the new file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not overwriting the .svn folder as well.

If you delete this folder or replace it with other folder you will be having some synchronization errors and/or svn integrity issues.

What you can do (and what I normally do with problems like this one) is to clear all .svn folders from your project filesystem and re-commit everything.

Please take a look at this article: http://thecrumb.com/2008/09/25/removing-svn-files-with-tortoisesvn/

And this one: http://www.anyexample.com/linux_bsd/bash/recursively_delete__svn_directories.xml

Answer (score 0):

> I have noticed that the last modified dates on the files are older than the ones they replaced

Like most other people, I would suspect that the files haven't changed. However, if they really have, does Subversion [detect changes](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#detectmodification) if you [touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435/windows-version-of-the-unix-touch-command) the file to update the last modified date?

Comment: No, I just touched one of the files and its not detecting any changes.

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me to commit. To outgo that issue, they may help you too.

- Check Out your svn repository folder in an empty folder on desktop.
  **C:\Users\ömer\Desktop\SpringWebTest**
- open the folder that you checked out, then select and copy the *.svn* folder and paste it in your project workspace.
  **C:\Users\ömer\workspaceLuna\SpringWebTest**
- now changes should be detected, finally commit the changes to svn repository.